# Displaying data on Android after retrieving data form Android Sq lite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am retrieving data according to dates but when running my app its shows nothing.

Here's my code :

SQL QUERY :

```
private Cursor getAllCurrentData()
    {
        String[] selectArg = new String[]{};

        return db.query(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME,
                null ,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ "= 2018-11-10",
                selectArg,
                null,
                null,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP);
    }
```

Displaying Data :

```
private  void totalMoney()
    {
        Cursor cursor = getAllCurrentData();
        double sum = 0.000d;
        double getMoney;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            getMoney = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.MONEY));

            sum += getMoney;
        }
        total.setText("Total money spent: " +sum);

    }
```

I am new to Android Programming. Where I am doing wrong ?. Please correct me

Comment: What does it display?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are connected to database and `cursor` returned by `db.query()` is not empty/null. Then Iterate over cursor like

```
 private void totalMoney()
    {
        openDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =  getAllCurrentData();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        double getMoney = 0;
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

           getMoney = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.MONEY));

            sum += getMoney;

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        total.setText("Total money spent: " + sum );

        closeDatabase();

    }
```